# Neo4j: Newsfeed Linked List parallel insertions

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm getting stuck with parallel insertions in Neo4J. I have been developing newsfeed with a linked list in this way:

```
(Resource)-[:NEWS]->(Latest_New)-[:NEXT]->(Second_latest)-[:NEXT]->...
```

I have the following query in order to insert at the head of the list ([:NEWS]->(latest_new)):

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (c:New) ASSERT c.head_id IS UNIQUE

MERGE (head: New {head_id: unique_id})
REMOVE head.head_id
WITH head
MATCH (resource)
WHERE resource.uid = resource_uid
OPTIONAL MATCH (resource)-[rel:NEWS]->(last_head)
WITH resource,head,rel, collect(last_head) as previous
DELETE rel
FOREACH (x IN previous | CREATE resource-[:NEWS]->(new_head:New {head_id: unique_id})-[:NEXT]->x)
WITH resource, head, rel
WHERE rel IS NULL
CREATE resource-[:NEWS]->head
SET header.head_id = unique_id
```

When I run this query sequentially all went fine. On the other hand, when I run it concurrently it only create empty (New) nodes without the relationships, and sometimes I got a deadlock. I'm confused with the locking behavior of MERGE + UNIQUE CONSTRAINT and other parallel stuff in Neo4j.

Do you have any idea on what is failing? Some explanation about the locking beaviour of MERGE + UNIQUE CONSTRAINT will be welcome. Thank you.